# Drawing piecewise-defined function using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pic

I have a function `f(x):=\hat{f}(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)`, where

```
\hat{f}(x) =     \left\{ \begin{array}{lcl}
  2x   & \mbox{for} & 0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{5} \\
  \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}(2x-1) & \mbox{for} & \frac{1}{5}\leq x \leq1
            \end{array}\right.
```

I am going to draw f(x) on the domain [-2,2] in latex via the tikzpicture.
My idea is the following:
Divide [-2,2] into pieces in order to define one function and draw.
But I am pretty sure there is a more clever way to draw it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[scale=0.5,domain=0:0.2,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{2*\x});
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And, please note that `mathjax` is not supported, therefore, please insert the image of your functions.

Comment: I tried the following: \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$x$};
      \draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
      \draw[scale=0.5,domain=0:0.2,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{2*\x});
    \end{tikzpicture} But it is not cleaver.

Comment: Please add a compilable version of your code in your question.